# default selected combobox in added value

Tags: javascript

> i used this code for adding new value in combobox, my problem is how
>   will i set every added value as selected?

```
<legend>Combo box</legend>
                Add to Combo: <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
                <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()">
                <br/>
                Combobox: <select name="combo" multiple id="combo"></select>
            </fieldset>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
    <script>
    function addCombo() {
        var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
        var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = textb.value;
        option.value = textb.value;
            option.value = textb.value;

        try {
            combo.add(option, null ); //Standard 
        }catch(error) {
            combo.add(option); // IE only
        }
        textb.value = "";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why did you add jquery tag to your question? It is only JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function addCombo() {
        var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
        var combo = document.getElementById("combo");
          
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = textb.value;
        option.value = textb.value;
            option.value = textb.value;
       option.selected = true;

        try {
            combo.add(option, null ); //Standard 
        }catch(error) {
            combo.add(option); // IE only
        }
        textb.value = "";
    }
```

```html
<legend>Combo box</legend>
                Add to Combo: <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
                <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()">
                <br/>
                Combobox: <select name="combo" multiple id="combo"></select>
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have added `combo.selectedIndex = combo.options.length-1;` to count all options and select the highest value. You have to decrement it, cause the index counts from zero.

```html
<legend>Combo box</legend>
Add to Combo: <input type="text" name="txtCombo" id="txtCombo"/>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()">
<br/>
Combobox: <select name="combo" multiple id="combo"></select>
</fieldset>
</BODY>
</HTML>
<script>
  function addCombo() {
    var textb = document.getElementById("txtCombo");
    var combo = document.getElementById("combo");

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;
    option.value = textb.value;

    try {
      combo.add(option, null ); //Standard 
      combo.selectedIndex = combo.options.length-1;
    }catch(error) {
      combo.add(option); // IE only
    }
    textb.value = "";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need jQuery for this:

```
option.prop("selected", true);
```